# Using Themroller with qTip 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2, themeroller

I am using [qTip 2.0](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/style/) on my site and it says I can use themeroller to style my tool tips. Yet I am a bit confused as how I use the themeroller with qTip? It has tutorials on its page but the section for Themeroller is blank.

Can anyone help me with this as I am stuck.

Here is my qTip Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j('.tool').qtip({
   content: 'Tool Tip Text',
position: {
  my: 'bottom left', 
  at: 'top left', 
  target: $j('.tool') 
  },
  style: {
  classes: 
  'ui-tooltip-tipsy' /*This is a style that comes with qTip 2.0 - I want to     
                       replace with a themeroller style.*/
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-shadow', // Optional shadow...
        tip: 'top center', // Tips work nicely with the styles too!

        /*
         * The important part: style.widget property

         * This tells qTip to apply the ui-widget classes to
         * the main, titlebar and content elements of the qTip.
         * Otherwise they won't be applied and ThemeRoller styles
         * won't effect this particular tooltip.
         */
        widget: true
    }
```

Needs to be added :)

Comment: Guess this is where I am a bit confused - I add widget: true, where and how does it point to the CSS for the themeroller style? Do I just put it into the same folder as qtip?

Comment: If you add Widget:true it uses the Classes from ThemeRoller. So you just need to have the ThemeRoller theme CSS file included in your head - and it should work out perfect :)